# Power BI - How to assign a Web URL to an image

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Hi I am a newbie in Power BI, and i am currently exploring different report programming techniques that i'm using in tableau and SSRS. In Power BI Desktop, how can i assign a web URL on an image.  When the user clicks the image (see sample below) it load another website.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps for adding URL to your image.

1. After adding image in Power BI, Create a measure with below code.

   Measure 2 = "https://www.google.com"
2. Set category as Web URL for the measure from top ribbon.

[image]

3. Now select type as "Web URL" and add that measure in **Web URL** under **Action** property of your image

[image]